# How to set server datetime as tomorrow in a moment

Tags: php

Sorry for my bad English. I have a task as *preview layout* (includes posts, videos, ...) *for tomorrow*. But my project's code is too much, I can not update code with another logic.

So, I have a idea: change the server's datetime to tomorrow with a moment (just only apply this datetime for current request, and this updated will not change real datetime of server) by special url, Example:

> access: mysite.com => will return response for now.
>
> access: mysite.com/preview => will return response for tomorrow.

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking. So what date/time functions are you using? Because your only option may be to create an override method that adds a day and do a search and replace on the method(s) you are using.

Comment: I use date() in php and the Carbon library, how can overide date() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the php `time()` function.

To do this you would need to install [Advanced PHP debugger](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php) extension.

Then you could do something like this:

```
rename_function('time', 'new_time');
override_function('time', null, 'return override_time();');

function override_time(){
    return time()+60*60*24;  
}
```

Alternatively, you could check out [this](https://github.com/hnw/php-timecop) extension.

Comment: Glad to help. BTW, which method did you use?